# locale dayname monthname in powershell

Tags: powershell, date, locale

I am trying to format a date in another locale.

The best I've come to is

```
$l1 =  'fr-FR' , 'de' , 'en-GB'

foreach ( $letter in $l1 ) {
    $culture = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo($letter)
    $date = get-date -Format $culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern

    echo ('culture locale = ' + $letter + ' > ' + $date )
    }
```

which gives

```
culture locale = fr-FR > mardi 10 mars 2020
culture locale = de > mardi, 10. mars 2020
culture locale = en-GB > 10 mars 2020
```

How can I have day name/month name spelled in their language ? (e.g. en-gb should give 10 march 2020)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-Date -Format` doesn't accept an actual format provider, only bare format strings.

Use [`DateTime.ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_ToString_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) to apply another culture altogether:

```
(Get-Date).ToString($culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern, $culture)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want custom date in another locale, `ToString` accept both format and culture.

```
$l1 =  'fr-FR' , 'de' , 'en-GB'

foreach ( $letter in $l1 ) {
    $culture = New-Object System.Globalization.CultureInfo($letter)
    $date = (Get-Date).ToString($culture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern, $culture)
    echo ('culture locale 2= ' + $letter + ' > ' + $date )
    $date = (Get-Date).ToString("dddd d MMMM H \Hr. m \min.", $culture)
    echo ('culture locale 3= ' + $letter + ' > ' + $date )

    }
```

gives

```
culture locale 2= fr-FR > mardi 10 mars 2020
culture locale 3= fr-FR > mardi 10 mars 15 Hr. 30 min.
culture locale 2= de > Dienstag, 10. März 2020
culture locale 3= de > Dienstag 10 März 15 Hr. 30 min.
culture locale 2= en-GB > 10 March 2020
culture locale 3= en-GB > Tuesday 10 March 15 Hr. 30 min.
```